# How to detect with feedparser if there are new items in an RSS channel?

Tags: python, python-2.7, rss, feedparser

I have the following code. When you understand the code, you can look at the two comments with
the capital letters. I could test if there are new items in the channel with `insert or ignore` but
I'm trying the better mechanism with utilization `feed.updated_parsed` attribute. Why doesn't it work
as expected?

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import feedparser
from sqlite3  import dbapi2 as sqlite
import sys, os
from datetime import datetime
from time import mktime
from daeutils import *
import re
import random
import optparse
import curses
import socket

def getActiveChannels():
  """Returns a list of active RSS channels"""
  con = sqlite.connect(connectionString)
  cur = con.cursor()
  cur.execute("select id, title, xmlurl, updated from channels")
  channels = cur.fetchall()
  cur.close()
  con.close()
  return channels

def getItemsForChannel(xmlUrl, lastUpdate):   
  socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)
  feedparserDictionary = feedparser.parse(xmlUrl)
  updatedTime = datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(feedparserDictionary.feed.updated_parsed))
  lst = datetime.strptime(lastUpdate, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
  if updatedTime < lst:
    return [] # HERE NOT BEHAVING CORRECTLY, WHEN I COMMENT THIS LINE, THERE MAY BE A FEW ITEMS

  items = feedparserDictionary.entries
  print "There are new %d items" % len(items)
  return items

def setChannelUpdateTime(xmlUrl, tm):
  con = sqlite.connect(connectionString)
  cur = con.cursor()
  cur.execute("update channels set updated = :tm where xmlurl = :xmlUrl", locals())
  con.commit()
  print "updated successfully"
  cur.close()
  con.close()

if __name__ == "_main__":
   con = sqlite.connect(connectionString)
   for channel in getActiveChannels():
     channelId, channelTitle, channelXmlUrl, lastChannelUpdate = channel
     countOfNewItems = 0
     items = getItemsForChannel(channelXmlUrl, lastChannelUpdate)

     for item in items:
       title, link, description, priority, updated = item
       cur = con.cursor()
       cur.execute("insert or ignore into feeds \
              (title, link, description, read, updated, channelid) \
              values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", \
              (title, link, description, 0, updated, channelId))

       countOfNewItems += cur.rowcount # WHICH ARE INSERTED HERE
       con.commit()
       cur.close()


     if countOfNewItems:
       print "Found new items"
       now = datetime.now().isoformat()
       if "." not in now:
         now = now + ".000000"
       setChannelUpdateTime(channelXmlUrl, now)
```

Here are the two tables in sqlite:

```
CREATE TABLE channels (id integer primary key, title string, text string, description string, type string, xmlurl string unique, htmlurl string, priority integer, active integer, deactivated integer, updated text);
CREATE TABLE feeds (id integer primary key, title string, link string unique, description string, read integer, priority integer, updated string, channelid integer, foreign key (channelid) references channels(id));
```

Comment: Can you please add what's missing in the "...". It's hard to determine what's going on without the context.

Comment: @PiAreSquared Now, I added only the relevant stuff + imports section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the possible error is that you are trying to compare `updated` field on the feed, the feeds could be not well supported by the feed creator. Or timezone formatting because of using isoformat or etc.

Anyway, I believe that it is much better to compare PER ENTRY `updated` properties rather than comparing the feed property which is mostly used for invalidating feed cache.

Here is a working example, where I return only new entries from the function.

```
import socket
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from time import mktime

import feedparser
from pprint import pprint


def getItemsForChannel(xmlUrl, lastUpdate):
    lst = datetime.fromisoformat(lastUpdate)

    socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)

    parsed = feedparser.parse(xmlUrl)

    items = [entry for entry in parsed.entries if
             datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(entry.updated_parsed)) > lst]
    print("There are new {} items".format(len(items)))
    return items


pprint(getItemsForChannel(
    'http://serverfault.com/feeds/tag/+or+linux+or+ubuntu+or+vim+or+rsync+or+gnome',
    (datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=3)).isoformat()
))
```

It uses from/to iso formatting for the last parsed date in your database value and compares entries per entry instead of global comparison based on the feed `updated` property.

Comment: Thank you, your solution with comparing per entry looks better. I hope there won't be unread items on the web (as in my solution), after I run the code.

Comment: You welcome! They shouldn't be there if all the timestamps are correct of course! :)